# .parentsUntil( $(e.target).parents('ul').length === 1 )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a standard list with multiple levels and I need to check the root of the particular item until

```
$(e.target).parents('ul').length === 1
```

Is it possible to use `.parentsUntil()` for this? Or is there another method I can use so I can check if the root of the list item has a particular class or not?

Comment: Something like `$(e.target).closest('ul').hasClass('something')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

**Description:** *For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree*.

Example of use:

```
if( $(e.target).closest('ul').hasClass('cls') ) {
     //do something
     alert('Class Found');
}
```

Comment: If you have `li > ul > li > ul > li...` this wouldn't bring up the root `ul`, would it not?

Comment: @TimMarshall No it won't. It will get the first match: ***For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector***

Comment: Thank you Aniket for explaining a little further :)

Comment: @TimMarshall Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**parentsUntil**](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)

`$(e.target).parentsUntil('ul.someClass')`

So it will select the `ul` with a class `someClass`

`.length` is use to check if it exist or not.